# Issues with SQL Having Clause

Tags: sql

When I try to execute the sql below, I'm getting an error message that says Invalid Column Name distance.  I havne't issued having in my sql's that much so I'm not sure what the isue is.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
SELECT ID, 
  3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(34.743305)) 
     * COS(RADIANS(Lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS(- 85.059586)) 
     + SIN(RADIANS(34.743305)) * SIN(RADIANS(Lattitude))) AS distance
FROM RetailerRegistration
HAVING (distance < 25)
```

Comment: Sometimes, the context where column aliases are usable depends on DBMS. Your code [works fine in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1021/6). You'll need to clarify what your DBMS is. PostgreSQL? Oracle? SQL Server? SQLlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`having` is used in conjunction with `group by`. I think you have it confused with `where`... Also, try putting the formula into the `where` clause as opposed to referencing the alias.

```
SELECT ID, 
  3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(34.743305)) 
     * COS(RADIANS(Lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS(- 85.059586)) 
     + SIN(RADIANS(34.743305)) * SIN(RADIANS(Lattitude))) AS distance
FROM RetailerRegistration
WHERE
  3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(34.743305)) 
     * COS(RADIANS(Lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS(- 85.059586)) 
     + SIN(RADIANS(34.743305)) * SIN(RADIANS(Lattitude))) < 25
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are attempting to reference an alias that you created in your SELECT list, I would suggest using a subquery and then use your alias:

```
select ID, distance
from
(
  SELECT ID, 
    3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(34.743305)) 
       * COS(RADIANS(Lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS(- 85.059586)) 
       + SIN(RADIANS(34.743305)) * SIN(RADIANS(Lattitude))) AS distance
  FROM RetailerRegistration
) d
where distance < 25;
```

The logical order of a processing a query is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

As a result the alias `distance` has not been defined yet for your WHERE clause.  One way to fix this would be to use a subquery.

Comment: Right, the contents of the SELECT list are not (logically) created until *after* the FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are executed, so their column aliases do not exist yet, and thus you cannot reference them in those clauses.

Answer (score -1):

you are not using any group by ..trying doing like this:

```
SELECT ID, 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(34.743305)) * COS(RADIANS(Lattitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS(- 85.059586)) + SIN(RADIANS(34.743305)) * SIN(RADIANS(Lattitude))) AS distance FROM RetailerRegistration where (distance < 25)
```

Having clause is used to impose condidtion on group of rows not individual rows

Hope this helps....

Comment: It is still saying that column name distance is invalid with the where clause.

Comment: `HAVING` clause works for individual rows in MySQL, at least.